# How do I change these modules so that the communication is bidirectional (inout)?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm simply not sure how to modify the code. I know i need to add an inout port but I don't know how to do it. I have watched multiple tutorials but I can't figure it out.

```
module mem(
  input  logic clk, we ,               // write enable bit, active low
  input  logic [n-1:0] in ,
  input  logic [m-1:0] addr ,
  output logic [n-1:0] out ) ;
  parameter n = 1, m = 1, k = 1 << m ; //data width, address width, size
  logic   [n-1:0] memo [k-1:0] ; 
  // array of 2^m elements, each being an n-bit wide register
  assign out = memo[addr] ;
  always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  if (! we ) memo[addr] = in ;
  end
endmodule
```

```
module stack(
  input  logic clk , rst ,            // clock and reset
  input  logic [1:0] op ,             //operation PUSH or POP (one-hot)
  input  logic [n-1:0] pushval ,      // PUSH argument
  output logic [n-1:0] popval ) ;     // POP result
  parameter n = 1, m = 1, k = 1<< m ; // data width, address width, size
  logic  [m-1:0] addr ;               // address for memory 
  logic  up, down ;                   // breaking op down to 2 separate bits
  logic  [n-1:0] in  ;                // input for memory
  logic  [n-1:0] out ;                // output from memory
  logic  we  ;                        // write enable signal for memory
  logic  [m-1:0] addr1 ;              // counter output
  assign up = (addr == {m{1'b1}}) ? 1'b0 : op[1] ;
  assign down = (addr == {m{1'b0}}) ? 1'b0 : op[0] ;
  assign in = (op == 2'b10) ? pushval : {n{1'b0}};
  assign we = rst ? 1'b1 : !(up ^ down) ;  
  assign addr = (op == 2'b10) ? addr1 + 1'b1 : addr1 ;
  // instantiate memory module

  mem #(n,m,k) memory(clk, we, in, addr, out) ;

  assign popval = out ;
  // instantiate counter module

  udl #(m) counter(clk, rst, up, down, addr1) ;

endmodule
```

Comment: you need to be more specific. which inout? why? it looks ok as it is.

Comment: I am just told to redesign the modules so that the data communication takes place through a bidirectional bus connection.

Answer (score 0):

a bus can be designed with multiple writers and readers. An example is the following:

```
wire bus;
assign bus = wren1 ? data1 : 'z;
assign bus = wren2 ? data2 : 'z;
```

In the above example the bus is driven either by data or by a high impedance value. Real data always wins. Just make sure that enable signals are not turned on at the same time, or you will get 'x' as the bus value.

you can read the bus value in a normal way, for example:

```
always_latch
    if (rden1)
        val = bus;
...
```

you can pass the `bus` wire through an inout port, for example

```
 module mem(input clk, wren, [3:0] address, inout[3:0] data);
   logic [3:0]memory[15:0];
   assign data = !wren  ? memory[address] : 'z;
   always_ff @(posedge clk) 
        if (wren)
            memory[address] <= data;
endmodule
```

similarly you can re-design you `stack` module.